# How to add cap_net_raw capability via a Makefile to c++ executable file on linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have created a c++ that runs on Linux and on of its functionalities is to ping on a provided host. The ping has been based on relevant Poco libraries. However in order to run successfully on linux the produced c++ executable file should have the `cap_net_raw` capability set by giving

```
setcap cap_net_raw=ep /bin/C++_APP
```

I have also used the following Makefile based on an example I found by googling.

```
CC := g++ 

# Folders
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
TARGETDIR := bin

# Targets
EXECUTABLE := C++_APP
TARGET := $(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

SRCEXT := cpp
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type f -name *.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(BUILDDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
CFLAGS := -c -Wall
INC := -I include -I /usr/local/include
LIB := -L /usr/local/lib -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil 

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
@echo " Linking..."
@echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
@mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
@echo " $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
@echo " Cleaning..."; 
@echo " $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)"; $(RM) -r $(BUILDDIR) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
```

I added the following command as the last build command

```
@echo "Setting Capabilities"; sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep   $(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)
```

However I got the following error:

> Failed to set capabilities on file `bin/NPT' (Invalid argument) The
>   value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the
>   file is not a regular (non-symlink) file

On the other hand when I give the command after the build of the c++ executable everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a regular file called `bin/NPT`? Also, where precisely did you add it? And why did you use `$(TARGETDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)` when existing lines use `$(TARGET)`?

Comment: @David Schwartz ,  Yes NPT is the actual name of the C++_app. I added the command before  clean: 
I got the same error when I used $(TARGET) as well

Comment: You might want to rely on `pkg-config` instead of hard-coding your own installation directories of external libraries (in this case, `/usr/local`) into the Makefile. This way, other people who might compile your program won't curse you... they will curse `pkg-config` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the command at the wrong place. You need to add it *after* the executable is made, not before. Try this:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
@echo " Linking..."
@echo " $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)"; $(CC) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIB)
@echo " Setting Capabilities"; sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep $(TARGET)
```